# What is virtual keyword in C programming?

Tags: c

I have come across this virtual Keyword in C programming, but actually how it will helpful for the programmers.

Comment: "I have come across this virtual Keyword in C programming..." Please share a citation so we can see it in context.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844471/virtual-functions-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since your question is tagged with the C language, maybe you're confused.

The word `virtual` is *not* a keyword in C.  It *is* a keyword in C++, but it is not part of the C language at all -- not even a reserved word.  You can use it as an identifier if you like.  But don't, because you will limit your program's ability to be ported to C++.

In C++ it is used to declare a class member function that is polymorphic.