# C++: Can a struct inherit from a class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, struct

I am looking at the implementation of an API that I am using.

I noticed that a struct is inheriting from a class and I paused to ponder on it...

First, I didn't see in the C++ manual I studied with that a struct could inherit from another struct:

```
struct A {};
struct B : public A {};
```

I guess that in such a case, struct B inherits from all the data in stuct A. Can we declare public/private members in a struct?

But I noticed this:

```
 class A {};
 struct B : public A {};
```

From my online C++ manual:

> A class is an expanded concept of a data structure: instead of holding only data, it can hold **both** data **and functions.**

Is the above inheritance valid even if class A has some member functions? What happen to the functions when a struct inherit them?  And what about the reverse: a class inheriting from a struct?

Practically speaking, I have this:

```
struct user_messages {
  std::list<std::string> messages;
};
```

And I used to iterate over it like this `foreach message in user_messages.messages`.

If I want to add member functions to my struct, can I change its declaration and "promote" it to a class, add functions, and still iterate over my user_messages.messages as I did before?

Obviously, I am still a newbie and I am still unclear how structs and classes interact with each other, what's the practical difference between the two, and what the inheritance rules are...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577465/in-c-can-i-derive-a-class-from-a-struct 
Looks like a duplicate of this question

Comment: is the for_each loop inside the class/struct or outside?

Comment: @chubsdad It's outside. A HTML template goes recursively over the messages.messages to render as HTML.

Comment: @augustin: My initial feel is to provide an 'iterator' design pattern to 'messages' class, rather than makeing the member 'messages' public.

Comment: @augustin: BTW, can you have a class with a member having the same name?

Comment: @augustin: though unrelated at the moment, the keywords 'struct' and 'class' have a small difference. the keyword 'class' can be used with templates but not the keyword 'struct' to define type parameters

Comment: @chubsdad Oops. I oversimplified my example. No the member has not the same name as the class. I edited the question accordingly. Thanks for all your other comments.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**Yes, struct can inherit from class in C++.**

In C++, *classes and struct are the same except for their default behaviour* with regards to inheritance and access levels of members.

### C++ class

- Default Inheritance = **private**
- Default Access Level for Member Variables and Functions = **private**

### C++ struct

- Default Inheritance = **public**
- Default Access Level for Member Variables and Functions = **public**

Comment: Thanks. That's clear. Does this mean that a struct can have member functions as well, including a constructor, and that we can create a new instance like for a class: <code>myObject = new myStruct(myVar)<code>?

Comment: Yes. Anything that's valid for a class is valid for a struct. They're absolutely and totally identical, except the access modifiers given above. There are no limits on mixing them or anything.

Comment: @DeadMG: Thanks. That's clear. I had looked for duplicates and didn't find them. I'm still glad I asked. Thanks.

Comment: You can even forward declare a struct as a class, and vice versa, but Visual C++ chokes on this under some conditions.

Comment: I still use structs for pure data, and classes when member functions are needed, even though they are the same. Force of habit.

Answer (score 52):

In C++

```
struct A { /* some fields/methods ... */ };
```

is equivalent to:

```
class A { public: /* some fields/methods ... */ };
```

And

```
class A { /* some fields/methods ... */ };
```

is equivalent to:

```
struct A { private: /* some fields/methods ... */ };
```

That means that the members of a struct/class [are by default public/private](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#In_detail).

Using `struct` also [changes the default inheritance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) to `public`, i.e.

```
struct A { }; // or: class A { };
class B : A { };
```

is equivalent to

```
struct A { }; // or: class  A { };
struct B : private A { };
```

And the other way around, this

```
struct A { }; // or: class A { };
struct B : A { };
```

is equivalent to:

```
struct A { }; // or: class A { };
class B : public A { };
```

Summary: Yes, a `struct` can inherit from a class. The difference between the `class` and `struct` keywords is just a change in the default private/public specifiers.

Comment: This should really be the chosen answer! Very clear.

Comment: The inheritance accessibility examples are incorrect. `struct A{}; class B : A{};` is equivalent to `class A{}; class B : private A {};`.  The accessibility of the base is determined by the derived being `class` or `struct`, not determined by the base being `class` or `struct`.

Comment: @Eljay, you are right, I had the examples mixed up. I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The only difference between a struct and a class is the default access level for members (private for classes, public for structs). This means that a struct should be able to inherit from a class, and vice-versa.

However, there is usually a difference in how structs and classes are used that is not mandated by the standard. structs are often used for pure data, ( or objects without polymorphism depending on your projects preference) and classes are used for the other cases. I emphasise that this is just a stylistic difference and not required.

Answer (score 7):

The main thing to understand is that structs come from C, whereas classes are C++. This means that although structs ARE first-class object-orientated citizens, they also have a legacy purpose, which is the reason for classes being separate and structs being default-access public. However, once this is done with, they're absolutely and totally identical and interchangable in every way.

Answer (score 5):

A struct is the same thing as a class except that a class defaults its members to private while a struct defaults its members to public. As a result, yes, you can inherit between the two. See [in C++, can I derive a class from a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577465/in-c-can-i-derive-a-class-from-a-struct).

Answer (score 4):

struct and class are pretty much interchangeable - just with different defaults in that classes default to private inheritance and members, structs to public.  The class keyword (and not struct) must be used for eg. "template <class T>".

That said, many programmers use the two to give a slight suggestion to a programmer reading the code: by using a struct you're subtly suggesting a less encapsulating, OO design.  A struct might be used internal to a library - where getting at the guts of it all is fair game, whereas classes are used on the boundary where API changes would inconvenience clients and better abstraction is useful.  This very loose convention has grown out of the difference in default accessibility - lazy/efficient/concise (take your pick) programmers do what's easiest unless there's a benefit otherwise, and not typing access specifiers is nice when possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Struct can inherit from a class and vice versa. The accessibility rule is

> $11.2/2- "In the absence of an
>   access-specifier for a base class,
>   public is assumed when the derived
>   class is declared struct and private
>   is assumed when the class is declared
>   class."

EDIT 2:
So you can change your class as:. Note that it is a **bad** idea to have public data members usually.

```
class user_messages {  // i also changed the name when OP was modified :)
public:   
   std::list<std::string> messages;  
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes a `struct` can inherit from a class. `struct` and `class` differ only in the access-specifier assumed for the members and for a base classes (or structs) if not specified explicitly in C++ . For structs it's `public`. For classes it's `private`.

The sentence you quote from the manual is about the concept of a class in C++, as compared to the concept of a data structure in C. In C++ new keyword - `class` was introduced to better reflect the change in the concept, but for compatibility with code in C, an old keyword `struct` was left and it's meaning is as described above.

Answer (score 1):

A class will not publicly inherit from a struct. A struct will publicly inherit from a class or a struct.

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
};
struct B : A
{};
```

B b;
b.a=5; //OK. a is accessible

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
};
struct B : public A
{};
```

It means the same.
B b;
b.a=5; //OK. a is accessible

```
struct A
{int a;};
class B : A
{};
```

B b;
b.a=5; //NOT OK. a is NOT accessible

```
struct A
{int a;};
class B : public A
{};
```

B b;
b.a=5; //OK. a is accessible

Finally:

```
class A
{int a;};
class B : A
{};
```

B b;
b.a=5; //NOT OK. a is NOT accessible

```
class A
{int a;};
class B : public A
{};
```

B b;
b.a=5; //NOT OK. a is NOT accessible