# c++ inheritance visibility mode

Tags: c++, inheritance

what is the default visibility mode of classes during inheritance
(here for B in D@ class)

```
class B {
public:
    int key;
    B(void) { key = 0; printf("B constructed\n");}
    virtual void Tell(void);
    ~B(void) {cout <<"B destroyed"<<endl << endl;}
};


class D2 : B {
public:
    void Tell(void) { printf("D2 Here\n"); }
};
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3574040/335858

Answer (score 8):

The default for when you use `class` is `private`, the default for when you use `struct` is `public`.

So this:

```
class D2 : B {
```

is equivalent to

```
class D2 : private B {
private:
```

and this:

```
struct D2 : B {
```

would be equivalent to

```
struct D2 : public B {
public:
```

Comment: private: in class body and public: in struct body are unnecessary as it is a default

Comment: @piotruś Did you read the question and do you realize that I was trying to show what is the default? Of course I have to repeat what is superfluous to show that!

Comment: the OP asked about what is the default inheritance mode, so if class A : B is equivalent to class A : public B or maybe class A : private B or anything else. The default qualifier inside the class definition is another issue, however I agree it is advisable to mention too